# Mixed class loading in Spring Boot causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloading

I have a fairly complex spring boot application with uses a bunch of 3:rd part packages, among others the org.ejml math library. This library is used by several jar files in my application, for instance by the stanford-nlp and my own tsne library and my own LDA library. The lda and tsne are built as fat JARs and include the entire ejml while the stanford-nlp packages it some other way. There are different versions of the EJML library, but all use a version of EJML library that implements a method called `subtract(DMatrixD1,DMatrixD1,DMatrixD1)` but when I run my Spring Boot application it throws an `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.ejml.dense.row.CommonOps_DDRM.subtract(org.ejml.data.DMatrixD1, org.ejml.data.DMatrixD1, org.ejml.data.DMatrixD1)'` how can this be?

I used the -verbose:class to try to figure out where the offending code was loaded, which it seems are from the LDA library (which uses ejml-0.41), but my code path starts in the tsne library (which uses the ejml-0.39), is this the cause of the problem? Can the 0.41 version of ejml not use a DMatrix1D object from the 0.39 version although they both implement the subtract method? If so how do I fix the problem, so that (spring/java) uses the correct (0.39 version I guess) for the subtract operation...

Comment: If you're not already, use a dependency management system like Gradle or Maven. Makes this kind of thing much easier.

Comment: Yes, I am using Maven, but I don't see how that would help in this case. I use several libraries, all of which include the EJML library

Comment: You can explicitly define the version you want in your pom. First one wins, so putting the desired version at the top of your pom will cause it to get used. This may or may not work in this case, but it's an option if you haven't tried specific versions yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options here. You could exclude the ejml-0.41 dependency from the LDA library, so it will use ejml-0.39, but this option it is not grantee to work. The second option, which is the correct one in my opinion, is to use a version of the LDA that uses ejml-0.39 or a version of the tsne library that uses ejml-0.41 in a way that there aren't different versions of the same dependency.

Comment: So you're saying that the cause of the problem, is that the code path starting in tsne which uses 0.39 of EJML but then the subtract operation tries to use the 0.41 version of EJML? Why does that happen?

Comment: I think maybe there are some differences in the two version of the library for that subtract method, so if you load one version, the code that use the other one will fail. This happens because of the way the classloader works, if there are multiple versions of the same class it will load the first one it finds, but you have no control on which one is the first.

Comment: You _do_ have control because the first one wins. Explicitly defining a version in your pom before the other dependencies will cause that version to be used.

Comment: Yeah sure, what I meant consider the context of the issue op has. You cannot say for dependency A load this version first and for dependency B load this other version first. You define one for all, which most likely is not going to solve op issue.